# Emulate No Signal/Service

Tags: android-emulator

Just wondering if it's possible to use the emulator, to emulate having no signal.

I've looked through the emulator documentation, and cant see an obvious way to do it.

Cheers

James

Answer (score 2):

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
gsm signal 0 0
exit
$
```

(Replace "5554" with the actual port that your emulator is running on - yes, its a year since this was asked, but perhaps people with google-fu will find this answer)